C++ class template: define a type used in superclass parameterization and value_type definition
I'm writing a small wrapper around iterators and my code ends up looking like this:
template <typename Iterator>
class Class: public Superclass<typename std::remove_reference<Iterator>::type::value_type> {
public:
   using value_type = typename std::remove_reference<Iterator>::type::value_type;

   explicit Class(Iterator&& iterator);

protected:
   Iterator iterator;
};

Class can be constructed with const references of rvalues, so I access the type of the elements after calling std::remove_reference and I use this type to parameterize the superclass and to define the value_type.
Is there a way to avoid writing typename std::remove_reference<Iterator>::type::value_type twice, for example by defining a local type?
Thanks,
Charlie

there is std::remove_reference_t which would mit it already a tiny bit shorter

Just move value_type to the base class.
If you need to use it in the derived class, you'll have to spell it as typename Class::value_type, but this doesn't affect the users of your class.

template<class Iterator, class ValueType=typename std::remove_reference<Iterator>::type::value_type>
class Class: public Superclass<ValueType> {
public:

etc.

If only there was some way to prevent the user from manually setting this template parameter.

@HolyBlackCat you can SFINAE it to make sure it is the default an nothing else :D

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Which requires you to spell the same type again to compare it with. D:

@HolyBlackCat I mean the user could just edit the header or use preprocessor defines.  At some point ya gotta accept hositile users are not your problem.

Shrug. When I see a default argument like this, my first thought is that it's an intended configuration point, unless there's a comment telling me otherwise.

Thanks, I went for HolyBlackCat's solution :)
